# Excel 2007 VBA to close powerpoint slideshow, but leave powerpoint application open

Tags: excel, vba, slideshow

I have an Excel file which needs to be able to move seamlessly (to the user) between excel sheets and powerpoint slidehow slides. I have been ble to make this work reasonably well, but it would probably work even better if I had a command to simply close the powerpoint slideshow that is running, rather than closing powerpoint itself (as this would allow for a quicker and better-looing start of the next powerpoint slide show). I am presently using this code:

```
Sub ViewVideo()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim PPApp As Object


        Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        PPApp.Visible = True
        PPApp.Presentations.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & VideoName
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(Delay))

        PPApp.Quit

        Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
        ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized

End Sub
```

However, this closes the Powerpoint application, not only the slide show. Is there a different command I could use?

Best regards
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same .Presentations but then .close

see code below:

```
PPApp.Presentations(videoName).Close
```

This works ofcourse as long as videoName is correctly defined or gets the proper filename string, see example below:

```
videoName = "test.pptx"
```